# API function `replace` doesn't replace a class with a CtClass instance

Tags: java, inria-spoon

I am trying to execute the following piece of code.

```java
System.out.println(originalElement);
System.out.println(uniqueParent);
((CtClass) originalElement).replace((CtClass) uniqueParent);
```

where

`originalElement` is

```java
class Already {}
```

and `uniqueParent` is

```java
class Already {
    class Klass {}
}
```

However, when I try to replace `originalElement` with `uniqueParent`, it doesn't work. I have tried the replace API with other elements such as `CtMethod` and it works there. I wanted to know if this is the intended behaviour with `CtClass` or is it supposed to be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize a discussion about this at the [Spoon forum](https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/issues/3827), the problem here concerns the semantics of `CtElement.replace`. The meaning is not that the invocation target takes on the same state as its argument. It means that the AST model which used to contain the invocation's target object as a node now contains the argument object as a replacement.

When you used `replace` on a `CtMethod`, you probably checked the change with a parent element such as a `CtClass` and not that `CtMethod` itself. Similarly, you could use `originalElement.getParent()` after replacement to get a part of the current model to check the change. In this case, it will return a `CtPackage` that has a type element referenced by `uniqueParent` instead of `originalElement`.